# Warning: Error in menuItem: could not find function "validateColor" after deploying in shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Afetr deploying the app in shiny server it is giving (Error in menuItem: could not find function "validateColor" after deploying in shiny server)
but it working fine in local server i dont know how to solve this error

```
   output$sidebar=renderUI({
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {
    sidebarMenu(
```

//in this menu item is throwing error after deploying on shiny server

```
menuItem("Charts",icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
               menuItem("Area Wise Sales", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"),
               menuItem(uiOutput("Box1")),
               menuItem(tabName = "dashboard",uiOutput("Box2"))),
               menuItem("Monthly Sales",icon=icon("bar-chart-o"),
                        menuItem(uiOutput("Box3"),
                                 menuItem(tabName ="dashboard1" ,uiOutput("Box4"))))


      ))


  }})


          output$boxxy=renderUI({
          if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {

    fluidPage(        
              # First tab content
            tabItems(
              # First tab content
              tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",  
fluidRow(tags$head(tags$style(HTML("table.dataTable tbody , table.dataTable.display tbody tr {
                                           background-color: #154360!important;
    }
                                           "))),
                 tags$style(HTML(".dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled {
                                 color: #0000ff !important;
  }")),box(
          width = 20, status = "info",solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE, background = "green",
          title = textOutput("text1"),
          plotlyOutput('plot')),
        box(

          width = 20, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,background ="light-blue",
          title = "Area Wise Sales",
          DT::dataTableOutput("view"))
            )),

#box ouput of per store 
tabItem(tabName = 'dashboard1',
box(
  width =6.5, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE, background = "green",
  title = textOutput("text3"),
  plotlyOutput('plot1')),

box(
  width =6.5, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,background ="light-blue",
  title = textOutput('text4'),
  plotlyOutput('plot2')
  ),
box(
  width = 10, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE, collapsible = TRUE,background ="light-blue",
  title = "STORE SALES PER MONTH ",
  dataTableOutput("view1"))

#box output of per store...........
)
)
)}      
})
```

ui.r
dashboardSidebar(

```
uiOutput("sidebar")
```

),
  dashboardBody(

uiOutput("boxxy"),

)
)

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: it means should i share a code or a screen shot of error

Comment: I means share the minimal code which produces the error.

Comment: have a look on it i had share code

Comment: `validateColor` is a non-exported function from the `shinydashboard` package. Have you tried updating the package on the server?

Comment: No i didnt try to update package

Comment: how to remove this  error i am stuck from yesterday

Comment: Any help why this is happening